# how to display multiple ember models on page

Tags: javascript, html, css, ember.js

I have an ember model with four FIXTURE instances. I'd like to display them all on the page at once. I'd like their position on the page to be one of either top, left, right or bottom. These values would be read from a property on the model. I'm new to client side development and ember. I'm not exactly sure what the best practices for something like this would be. I get the sense that the positioning should be done in css. I know I need to use an Ember.ArrayController for my model but I'm lost as to how to go about doing this. A little nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2HCLn/8/)

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="server">
{{region}}    
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="servers">

{{#each 'server'}}
    {{region}}
{{/each}}

</script>

    App.Server = DS.Model.extend({

    region: DS.attr('string')

}).reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
        {
            id:1,
            region: "North"

        },
        {
            id:2,
            region: "South"
        },
        {
            id:3,
            region: "East"
        },
        {
            id:4,
            region: "West"
        },

    ]

});

.north {

}

.east {

}

.south {

}

.west {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick example with your data.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/354/edit

And another example with your data in the servers route.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/355/edit

The main idea is you have a router which defines urls for your app.  Different urls are backed by routes, routes are used for obtaining models which back the template which is used for that route.  And you need to use the store in order to obtain records if you're choosing to use Ember Data.

I'd recommend going through the guides on Ember's site to start a foundation.  http://emberjs.com/guides/  Good luck and feel free to ask more questions on the site as you have them!

```
App.ServersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.get('store').find('server');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm still unclear as to how to display all the models on the page at once. Is this a limitation of the {{each}} helper? Is there another helper that will display all the elements in the model at once? I figured out a way to manage the position of each element on the page using css ie.

    .north{
      left: 357px;
      top: 96px;
    }
I'm able to use the link-to helper to access these elements one by one but would like to use a different helper that just plops them all on the screen. Will I have to create my own helper for this? Is this even possible?